# How to format this string of type TimeSpan

Tags: c#

I have a string with this format :

```
"09:00"
```

i want convert this string for this format:

```
 "9h"
```

what is the simplest way to format this string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation page entitled [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#other-characters):

- We can parse a `string` to a `TimeSpan` using [`TimeSpan.Parse(value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_Parse_System_String_)
- We can use [`%h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#hSpecifier) to get the hour component.
- We can use [`'h'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#other-characters) to add the literal text "h".

Putting that together:

```
string formatted = TimeSpan.Parse("09:00").ToString("%h'h'"); // 9h
```

Note that `TimeSpan.Parse("09:00")` will only work if your culture is able to parse the timespan in this format. It might be safer to pass in a culture value to an [appropriate overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) of `TimeSpan.Parse`. For example:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("09:00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Assuming that your culture/locale is able to parse "9:00".  Also note that the trailing "h" may need an escape character.  TimeSpan.ToString is very fussy

Comment: @Flydog57 the quote is the escape character unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation: _"There are two ways to include a literal character in a format string: Enclose it in single quotation marks (the literal string delimiter)."_. You're absolutely right about the culture thing, and I'll add a note for that.

Comment: I hate `TimeSpan.ToString`. I tend to end up sprinkling backsplashes all through my format strings. I've never used single quotes before.